# Why did Mad Eye need to use the trophy as a portkey when he could have used anything else?

Tags: harry-potter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was the Triwizard Cup used as the portkey?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/why-was-the-triwizard-cup-used-as-the-portkey)

In an otherwise untainted and freakin' awesome series, J.K. Rowling leaves a hole that cannot be ignored: ***Why did Moody, and Voldemort for that matter, need to arrange the whole thing with the trophy?***

Once established in Hogwarts and as Harry's teacher, it would have been a relatively simple matter for Moody to invite Harry into his office, as he had already done, and said " Here Harry, drink this tea?," (The cup of course bieng a portkey and on the desk to begin with so Moody is not touching it), and Goodbye Harry, Hello Voldy!